# Extraction Failed. "the file name, directory name, of volume label syntax is incorrect"

Tags: windows-vista, installation, windows-registry, visual-studio-2008

When I install the Visual Studio 2008 on my Windows Vista, I saw the error message box "the file name, directory name, of volume label syntax is incorrect". How do I fix it? I have already changed registry setting, but it doesn't work. Please share your experience. Thanks.

Comment: How did you change the registry settings?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are getting that error from the installer. If so, it sounds like the msi file, or one of its dependents, is corrupt. I sugget you download the file again, and check that the size (and if possible, the md5 hash) are correct, prior to attempting re-installation.

Good luck!